# Can't connect to sql server from lan computer using windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

This is the thing, I have a server working perfectly allowing LAN connections, now im setting up a second one for maintenance purposes, but for some reasons I can't connect to him using windows authenticacion, but I still can to the first one, or using sql server login but I dont what to, I want to use Windows Authenticacion... I keep getting error message:

> *login failed for user "the user is not associated with a trusted SQL connection. (microsoft sql server, error:18452)*

UPDATE: Both servers are running under Windows 7 (they are not for buissness use) they both are configure exactly equal.

UPDATE 2: I can connect from the same computer but not from a network one.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332

Comment: Thanks Kritner, but I dont want to use SQL Login, I actually can, but I dont want

Comment: **(1)** Does that server even support Windows Authentication? **(2)** If yes - does your current Windows user have a **login** on that server?? **(3)** If yes again - does that login have a **user** in the database you're trying to connect to??

Comment: How do I check if Windows Authentication is enable in W7?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Are you using just `username` or are you specifying `domain\user` or `server\user`?

Comment: Im "connecting" to `jefatura-pc\jarvis` same syntax as in the working sql server `server-pc\renta`

Comment: Im using SQL Server 2005 on both computers

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server 2005 are you using? SQL Server **Express** by default doesn't allow remote connections (from a separate PC)

Comment: SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few time, I realize the problem was at the layer eight (me), the best way to use windows authentication for SQL server is configuring a domain server, then add those domains users to sql and give them the desired privileges to connect to a database, and that' all it's that simple (at least for me it was) so after that, I created a System DSN Connection using windows authentication.